# If/Else in SQL Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

I want to use IF condition in my SQL query's WHERE clause. But the comparison should be from another table's columns. Simply, my pseudo-code is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE
 (if DATE from TABLE2 = 0000 then select ID from TABLE2 as TABLE1.ID 
 else if ID from TABLE2 = 00 then select DATE from table2 as TABLE1.DATE)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you joining Table1 and Table2? do they have a common field that you're using to link them? The results you're after would be a simple CASE in the select statement if you can join these tables together.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? There sp's are far from compatible...

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudo code is quite vague, but as far as I understood it, something like this should work:

```
SELECT TABLE1.* 
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 
   ON   (TABLE2.DATE = '0000' AND TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID)
     OR (TABLE2.ID = '00' AND TABLE2.DATE = TABLE1.DATE)
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9571b/1).

Comment: does inner join change the original table? because i dont want to change the original table. i'm gonna pull specific date or id number according to second table and call that values from first table.